# Powershell Delete first word only of a line

Tags: powershell

My Text File has below content:

```
author   : abc  
Revision : 123  
Date     : 9/4/2018 11.15.50 AM  
Path     : testabc  
Message  : Req ID:abcd1234  
           Rev:1.0.0  
           Status:something   
           Notes:somethingabc  
Path : D:\temp
```

I want this content to look like this below:

```
author   : abc  
Revision : 123  
Date     : 9/4/2018 11.15.50 AM  
Path     : testabc  
Req ID:abcd1234  
Rev:1.0.0  
Status:something   
Notes:somethingabc  
Path : D:\temp
```

I need to delete the word "Message  :" only (in the 5th line) and remove the spaces for the next three lines.

I have tried below:

```
$content = Get-Content "D:\test.txt"
$content | Foreach {$_.TrimStart('Message  : ')} |  Foreach {$_.TrimStart()} | Set-Content "D:\test.txt"
```

Comment: `(Get-Content .\test.txt ) -replace "^(Message\s+:\s+|\s+)"`

Comment: Thanks @LotPings .., It worked!!!

Comment: Thanks, script0207. @LotPings, can you please post your comment as an answer, along with an explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `-replace` operator, like this

```
$lines = Get-Content "D:\test.txt"
$lines -replace "Message  : " -replace "^\s+" | Set-Content "D:\test.txt"
```

Notes:

- `-replace "A","B"` replaces `A` with `B`. If you omit `B`, it effectively removes `A` (i.e. replaces it with nothing).
- `-replace` can be chained
- `-replace` works with regular expressions, `^\s+` means *"multiple spaces at the start of the line"*
- Many Powershell operators can work with arrays. There is no need to use `ForEach` here - `Get-Content` gives you an array of lines, `-replace` runs for every line.

Answer (score 3):

The IMO easiest way is the RegEx based `-Replace` operator.

```
(Get-Content .\test.txt ) -replace "^(Message\s+:\s+|\s+)"
```

See the RegEx working [here with an explanation](https://regex101.com/r/tCW5YG/1)

The RE anchors at line begin `^` and has an [alternate](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) it matches either

- `Message\s+:\s+` literal Message followed by at least one space a colon and at least one space
  Or `|`
- just spaces or more precise any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)

And replaces them with nothing `,""` which hasn't to be expressed but is implied.